# Files within the application remain even after uninstallation

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have created some files within my `Xamarin Forms` application. but although I uninstall the application from the phone and debug again with `VisualStudio`, the files inside remain, with everything that was previously saved. How could I solve?

```
 string DbLocal = Path.Combine(FileSystem.AppDataDirectory, "DbLocal.db3");
 string Emoji = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "Emoji.json");
```

Comment: Whats the path of Dblocal? maybe you are storing it outside of your local cache

Comment: I do not provide further information on the application. I only insert those 2 strings but despite having uninstalled everything, I find again after installing the app again, the files that were present inside them

Comment: but which of the file is not getting deleted of both?

Comment: For example the DbLocal File has a database, but it remains with some elements previously saved in it. It doesn't always happen, but it often does

Comment: you said like - `the files inside remain` .... i mean which file was it? db or json? & why are you creating json file!

Comment: Both remain! How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: try with the below path, let me know if theres problem in that as well

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this while creating your DB.

```
public readonly SQLiteAsyncConnection dbContext;
private string dbPath;
switch (Device.RuntimePlatform)
{
                case Device.iOS:
                    dbPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "..", "Library", "DbLocal.db");
                    break;
                case Device.Android:
                    dbPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "DbLocal.db");
                    break;
}
dbContext = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(dbPath);
```

Using this path for DB will delete the actual DB file created when you uninstall the application.

---------------------------- EDIT ---------------------------

The file here was deleted cuz the path I used to create DB was the internal system cache path of that application which usually gets cleaned when you remove the application from device. The path is something like `InternalStorage->Android/Data/com.packagename.appname/INTERNAL_CACHE_FILES`.

Remember that its the internal storage, not the external storage one. You need to set root permissions to check for files, or you can browse the path through `Android Studio` for Emulators

To delete the json file permanent, you can get the path of the json file & check weather the file is present or not, if the file is present, just delete it. For that you can try something like

```
if(File.Exists(Emoji))
{
   File.Delete(Emoji); //Emoji is path for your json file
}
```

Comment: It works! Can you tell me how to permanently delete the json file too? For each file do I have to make this distinction between ios and android? Could you please explain to me why in the way you wrote me the file is then deleted?

Comment: @StefanoAPP you can try to set `android:allowBackup="false"` in the application tag in `AndroidManifest.xml`, maybe Android OS was restoring from a backup every time 
 you deployed the app.

Comment: @StefanoAPP check the edit, let me know if you wanna know something more about it. you can mark the answer as correct & a upvote would be helpful:)

Comment: Can I ask you why on Ios you indicate a different path than that of Android?

Comment: Cuz android & iOS has different internal architecture. OS for both works completely different

Comment: At first it seemed to work, but today I ran into the same problem again

Comment: I also add that trying to change the folder in which to read the file, as soon as I start the app, the database should be empty because the application should look for it in another path, instead I still find the same elements as before

Comment: @StefanoAPP can you try my advice?

Comment: I still cant understand whats your actual issue is, can you edit your question with more details & code sample your tring @StefanoAPP